# non atomic measures in Riesz theorem

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, riesz-representation-theorem

In class we work with the next version of the Riesz theorem:

Given $X$ a compact metric space and $I$ a positive, linear and continuous functional on $C(X)$, there exists a unique Borel measure $\mu$ on $X$ for which $I(f)=\int_X f d\mu$ for every $f\in C(X)$.

I wonder if there is any standard condition on the $I$ operator, such that the measure $\mu$ is non atomic.

Comment: you mean something like "The measure $\mu$ associated to this operator is non-atomic if and only if there is no bounded sequence $f_n$ of functions with monotonically decreasing support to a singleton such that $I(f_n)>c>0$"?

Comment: @Bananach: That was the first thing I had in mind. So I decided to ask, because there maybe some property "known" operator $I$.

Comment: The measure is atomic if and only if $I$ is multiplicative, i.e.,
$I\left(fg\right)=I\left(f\right)I\left(g\right)$. This is in Rudin's
Functional Analysis, Example 11.13. (I'm sure it can be found in many
other books on Banach algebras.)

Comment: Thanks, I 'll read the book more carefully.

Comment: @James: I was reviewing the example mentioned, but I can not understand it. Could you explain this example please.